# Recursive Function

Tags: c, recursion

Given the following recursive function, what would be printed by mysterious(4)?

```
void mysterious(int x) {
    if (x == 0) return;
    printf(“%d ”, x);
    mysterious(x-1);
    mysterious(x-1);
}
```

Here is my call stack:

```
mysterious(4) => print 4
mysterious(3) => print 3
mysterious(2) => print 2
mysterious(1) => print 1
mysterious(0) => print 0
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Somebody uses the function name `mysterious` in all their exam questions? :)

Comment: sorry, time for you to do them yourself

Comment: And what's so mysterious about it? Is compiling and running it more difficult than posting on SO?

Comment: OP has stated in comments that it's _not_ homework and, anyway, homework is a meta-tag that adds nothing to the question. If questioners want help rather than answers, they will ask for help. On top of that, I'm voting this up since (1) OP at least had a crack at it first; (2) it _is_ useful in understanding recursion and clear in intent; and (3) I like annoying drive-by downvoters :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: OP could first: 1) Run it to see the actual output. 2) Use a debugger. 3) Use different values for input and observe the differences. 4) Check Wiki page about recursion.

Comment: @paxdiablo: but at least with this way I get useful diagrams

Comment: Or: (5) ask the people who would know, the ones that will go out of their way to _explain_ as well. At a bare minimum both Startgazer and myself have gone above and beyond to educate OP with hopefully lucid prose and useful diagrams and, as painful as this is, I do have to admit Stargazers diagram is a better one than mine :-)

Comment: indeed but they were both equally helpful

Comment: See my comment on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467713/recursive-function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you just type it in to an editor in your language of choice, compile it and run? I chose Java but that's just because I'm between CygWin installs on my box at the moment - I'd much rather be using C :-)

```
public class testprog {
    public static void mysterious(int x) {
        if (x == 0) return;
        System.out.print(x + " ");
        mysterious(x-1);
        mysterious(x-1);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        mysterious(4);
    }
}
```

This outputs the numbers:

```
4 3 2 1 1 2 1 1 3 2 1 1 2 1 1
```

Basically, what's happening is that, at each level, you print out the number then call the next level twice with the next lowest number (unless it's reached zero).

> Aside: technically, you *do* call the next layer with zero but, since it returns straight away, it has no affect on the output.

The following diagram will hopefully illustrate this better, with different symbols representing different layers:

```
(4) (-------------------------------) (-------------------------------)
     {3} {-----------} {-----------}   {3} {-----------} {-----------}
          [2] [1] [1]   [2] [1] [1]         [2] [1] [1]   [2] [1] [1]
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. So essentially, it's the double mysterious(x-1) that causes the next lowest number to be called twice?

Answer (score 7):

Because every function call makes 2 function calls in turn, you can visualize your recursion as a "tree" so to speak, and you are doing a preorder traversal on the tree.

It would look something like this:

```
                           4
                           |
                3----------+----------3
                |                     |
           2----+----2           2----+----2
           |         |           |         |
        1--+--1   1--+--1     1--+--1   1--+--1
```

The order of execution that you have is:

- print the number
- call the function with x-1
- call the function with x-1 again

This would correspond to our "tree visualization" by doing:

- print the root
- traverse the left node
- traverse the right node

The output would be:

```
    4 3 2 1 1 2 1 1 3 2 1 1 2 1 1
```

Comment: That's what I had thought. Would it actually not print all of these on a single line with one space between each number? There are no new line `\n` characters in the print statement... That's what I thought would happen - but I don't work with C much.

Comment: @jeremyawesome, very observant :). I changed the output.

Answer (score 2):

No, it will be

```
mysterious(4) => print 4
mysterious(3) => print 3
mysterious(2) => print 2
mysterious(1) => print 1
mysterious(1) => print 1
mysterious(2) => print 2
mysterious(1) => print 1
mysterious(1) => print 1
mysterious(3) => print 3
mysterious(2) => print 2
mysterious(1) => print 1
mysterious(1) => print 1
mysterious(2) => print 2
mysterious(1) => print 1
mysterious(1) => print 1
```

because 0 will cause the function to return earlier and because of that double-call.

Answer (score 1):

No. It won't print `0` cause when `x==0` it will return

Also, since you have

```
mysterious(x-1);
mysterious(x-1);
```

it will print *(Fixed)*

```
4 3 2 1 1 2 1 1 3 2 1 1 2 1 1
```

`mysterious(x-1);` doesnt change the value of `x`. it just calls `mysterious()` again, this time with the value `x-1`

Comment: what does "return;" mean? I'm not used to seeing return without a statement following it.

Comment: when in a void function (a function which does not return a value) using return means exit the function and return to the callee

Comment: 4 3 2 1 1 2 1 1 3 2 1 1 2 1 1 - 4 only once and then branches out for each successive call

Comment: Wrong, that double-call is inside the function.

Comment: @Peter,@thejh. Correct. Will fix.